# Jsoup doesn't follow the server redirect for this url: http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/BIPRU/6

Tags: jsoup

When hit the url in browser (IE9 or Chrome latest):

```
http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/BIPRU/6
```

The brower is redirected to:

```
http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/handbook/BIPRU/6
```

However if I use

```
Jsoup.connect("http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/BIPRU/6").get()
```

The redirect doesn't happen and the returned page is an error page.

Is this a bug in Jsoup? Is there any fix?

Answer (score 0):

The server seems to expect a valid session cookie. If you call the URL without cookies, the server adds `;jsessionid=...` to the destination URL. This leads to another 302 redirect to the error page you see.

So, if you get some valid session cookies before you request the redirect, everything is fine:

```
Connection.Response response;
response = Jsoup.connect("http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/").execute();
response = Jsoup.connect("http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/BIPRU/6")
                .cookies(response.cookies()).execute();
```

Then you get the desired result:

```
assertEquals("http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/handbook/BIPRU/6",
              response.parse().baseUri());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

Jsoup.connect("http://fshandbook.info/FS/html/FCA/BIPRU/6").followRedirects(true).get();